# How to write systemd service to ensure start after dns service?

Tags: networking, dns, systemd, 19.04, systemd-resolved

After upgrading to Kubuntu 19.04, I don't know how to write a service so that it can start after DNS service has been initialized.

In this past, I just use `After=network.target`, but now it doesn't work. I also tried `After=network-online.target`, but no luck.

So I think the problem is `systemd-resolved`, how could I solve this problem?

---

update:

```
ERROR: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
ERROR: failed to resolve the provided hostname
```

These are two related logs. So I can confirm the problem is related to DNS service.

Comment: If `systemd-resolved` is the problem, why not use `After=systemd-resolved.service`? But it sounds as if you are not really sure if that is really your problem, so I would recommend to find the source of the problem first. Look at the service log and `journalctl`.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, I've updated the problem.

Comment: Does the name resolution work when the system is fully booted and you are logged in? `ping www.google.com` or does your service start then if you start it manually?

Comment: @Thomas And the reason why I didn't use `After=systemd-resolved.service` is that `systemd-resolved.service`'s unit says `Before=network.target`. So if I use `After=network.target`, it implicitly `After=systemd-resolved.service`.

Comment: @Thomas Definitely, it works seamlessly. I can directly use `systemctl start myservice.service` to start it.

Comment: Argh...didn't see the relation between `systemd-resolved.service` and `network.target`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93820/discussion-between-thomas-and-sraw).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please add a dependency in your service file:

```
After=nss-lookup.target
```

This should ensure that host/name lookup is operable.

Further details are in the documentation:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html

> **nss-lookup.target**
>
> A target that should be used as synchronization
>   point for all host/network name service lookups. Note that this is
>   independent of UNIX user/group name lookups for which
>   nss-user-lookup.target should be used. All services for which the
>   availability of full host/network name resolution is essential should
>   be ordered after this target, but not pull it in. systemd
>   automatically adds dependencies of type After= for this target unit to
>   all SysV init script service units with an LSB header referring to the
>   "$named" facility.

To fully wait for network, the documentation of systemd https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/ directs you to add to your service:

```
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
```

and to confirm that the relevant "wait" service is enabled:

```
$ systemctl is-enabled NetworkManager-wait-online.service systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
disabled
enabled
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it just doesn't work. I am also really confused about this problem...

Comment: can you confirm that you have the `Before=nss-lookup.target` dependency in your copy of `systemd-resolvd.service`?

Just to be sure and in line with the documentation: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/

You did add `After=network-online.target` **and** actively request this target by `Wants=network-online.target` and it still does not have network when your service starts? Can you double-check the startup sequence? `systemd-analyze plot >startup.svg`gives a nice graphical overview.

Comment: It does work when I change `network.target` to `network-online.target` :) I see that `network-online.target` is a very late target in the startup sequence. BTW, although my service runs after `nss-lookup.target` all the time, it only works when I change to `network-online.target`.

Comment: The documentation of systemd hides this a bit. `nss-online.target` allows your service to communicate with the resolver. In case you need the network to be up and running to have the resolver contacting other systems then the network needs to be running. For this purpose exists a one-shot service which waits (long) for the network. `systemctl cat systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` shows details of this service, which is ordered before `network-online.target`.

Comment: `systemctl is-enabled NetworkManager-wait-online.service systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` -> `Failed to get unit file state for NetworkManager-wait-online.service: No such file or directory` on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @ÍhorMé please check your installation. Maybe you missed to install a package. Here is a link to the relevant man-page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.8.html

Comment: @user228505 Maybe, it's just not present on 20.04 anymore. I do seem to have it on 18.04, but not on 20.04.

Comment: @ÍhorMé version 20.04 is focal. Package list shows this file at least in amd64 architecture: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/network-manager/filelist

Answer (score -1):

See the unit file at the end of this ...
https://systemd.io/NETWORK_ONLINE/

IOW to delay until your system can resolve DNS, you need to create a new dependency unit for network-online which actually tests the name resolution.  This will not work if, for example the system suspends, since the network-online.target dependency was satisfied before the suspend.

Better to include a test in your application.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1280219)